# Accessing variables passed to, or defined in, parent R function

Tags: r, function

If a variable is not defined in the scope of a function, R is said to look in for the variable in the parent environment, then the parent of that environment, and so forth.

This does not seem to be the case where variables are passed to functions:

```r
Foo <- function (y) {
  message('In Foo, x = ', x)
}

Func1 <- function (x = 1) {
  message('In Func1, x = ', x)
  Foo(1)
  lapply(1:2, Foo)
}

Func2 <- function () {
  x <- 2
  message('In Func2, x = ', x)
  Foo(1)
}

Func1(x = 1) # Foo throws error
Func2() # Foo throws error
x <- 99 
Func2() # Now Foo uses value of x from global environment


remove(x)
```

How do I enable the function `Foo` to search the parent function, and its parents, for the value of the variable, rather than using the value in the global environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `Foo` is defined in the global environment.

Adding the line

```r
  environment(Foo) <- environment()
```

before calling Foo within `Func1` and `Func2` produced the desired behaviour.

Comment: In case it is not obvious: Relying on scoping for this is bad practice. Always pass `x` as a function argument.

Answer (score 3):

You want to look up variables in the *calling stack* rather than in the *enclosing environment* (dynamic scoping). You can use `dynGet` in `Foo`, which looks for an object in the callers, i.e., the sys.frame()s of the function. `dynGet()` is somewhat experimental. **Use with caution.**

```
Foo <- function (y) {
  message('In Foo, x = ', dynGet("x", inherits = TRUE))
}
```

See also: [Function environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs)

Comment: "Use with caution."